# Download Freebase Simple topic dump

Tags: freebase

I was trying to download the basic simple offline topic dump of the Freebase entities but I think there are currently no such links. This is the old link: http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv.bz2

Is this data available somewhere? It would be great if the data can be made available once again. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple topic dump is no longer being generated and Google has indicated that the RDF dump will be the only dump format going forward.

Comment: Is there a way to take some subset of data for testing. Let's same all the nodes connected to some 100 personalities. How easy it is to extract that info?

Comment: I see you've posted that as a separate question, which is really what it is, so I'll leave that as the canonical place for answers.